# LifecycleRegistryOwner class is deprecated

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I am using the Room database from Android architecture component. So for `LiveData` I am implementing the `LifecycleRegistryOwner` interface in my activity. As there is alternative solution to use `LifeCyceActivity` but my activity is already extending `BaseActivity` so I can't do it.

What is alternative of `LifecycleRegistryOwner`?

Answer (score 7):

As seen in [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleRegistryOwner.html)

> This interface was deprecated in API level 1.0.0.
>
> **Use android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity** which extends **LifecycleOwner**, so there are no use cases for this class.

Which means, that if your activity is a descendent of `AppCompatActivity`, than it already implements `LifecycleOwner` interface.

These changes are introduced in support libs version [26.1.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#26-1-0).

Comment: Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: If the BaseActivity above was extending AppCompatActivity, then it will be OK. However, what if you cannot extend AppCompatActivity? I am extending GvrActivity (I have to) so I cannot extend AppCompatActivity. What do I do in this case?

Comment: @jclova `AppCompatActivity` is a descendant of [`SupportActivity`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/support-library-27.1.0/compat/src/main/java/android/support/v4/app/SupportActivity.java#38), which does the magic.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs :

`This interface was deprecated in API level 1.0.0.
Use android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity which extends LifecycleOwner, so there are no use cases for this class.`

Link [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LifecycleRegistryOwner.html)